# Using OpenGL GLSL 3.3 in a 2.1 context

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, nvidia, glfw

I have an old Nvidia card (Go GeForce 7400) which I know supports only OpenGL 2.1. Even if I force GLFW to create a 3.3 context on this machine, the program is guaranteed to crash or returns a `NULL` window. However, I found the machine can actually run some simple shaders written in GLSL version 3.3 under a 2.1 context. They even have `#version 330 core` version declarations. To my suprise, the program did not complain while compiling these shaders and everything seems to work.

So here is what I did:

1. Create a context using GLFW and specifically passed 2.1 as version number.
2. Load and compile shaders written in GLSL 3.3, and everything works like magic.

To my understanding, GLSL 3.3 comes only with OpenGL 3.3+. And before that, the GLSL version for OpenGL 2.1 is actually 1.20. So can anyone tell me what happened? Is this because my graphic card's driver has ``secretly'' implemented GLSL 3.3 but supports only OpenGL 2.1 APIs? What is the chance to find this kind of weird combination to work in general? I'm pretty sure I shouldn't assume GLSL 3.3 to work in a 2.1 context in genral, should I?

BTW I think I am using Linux Nvidia proprietary driver for the card.

Comment: Most of the time, the only differences between OpenGL versions is what extensions the drivers are required to support. Your graphics card might support all the features of GLSL 330 but not all of the extensions required by OpenGL 3.3.

Comment: Or it just means you can use GLSL 3.3 syntax (f.i. "in" and "out" qualifiers instead of "attribute" or "varying") in the shader programs. What does `glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);` return?

Comment: I have just tested glGetString, it returns GLSL version 1.20 as I suspected. The full text says "Version 1.20 NVIDIA via Cg compiler".

Comment: After playing with it more, here are a few things I noticed: 1) it supports in/out syntax as in one of the comments; 2) It also allows to write fragment shader in 3.3 fashion as a single output vector variable rather the deprected gl_fragColor as output. 3) Occasionally, it complains 3.3 is not fully implemented but when I have syntax errors in my program, i haven't seen any specific unsupported feature yet. BTW apology for late reply, this old laptop just went down soon after I posted the question.